# "Pricing European Options in a Stochastic-Volatility-Jump Diffusion Model" ,does anyone have this article?

Tags: option-pricing, stochastic-volatility, jump-diffusion

I can't find the article  "Pricing European Options in a Stochastic-Volatility-Jump Diffusion Model" of
Thomas Knudsen and Laurent Nguyen-Ngoc, Journal of Financial and Quantitative Analysis, submitted.
Does anyone know where I can find it, or can send it to me directly. I really need it. Thanks.

Comment: I don't have it, but I took a quick look and I get the impression that it was a Deusche Bank technical note, which never got published in the journal, but may be in the book: [Marcus Overhaus, Andrew Ferraris, Thomas Knudsen, Ross Milward, Laurent Nguyen-Ngoc, Gero Schindlmayr. Equity Derivatives: _Theory and Applications_. Wiley (2001)](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0471436461)

Comment: Dear Dimitri, thanks for your answer. I have already check the book "Equity Derivates..." but there is notihing about the article, I don't know what I can do for find it.

Comment: very sorry, then I don't know. The book cites the article (pp 116 and 216 [72]) but says that the article has more details  . Maybe someone at DB has a copy.